# How to import vue components?

Tags: vue.js

In a tutorial I have seen this way to import a component:

export default {
name: 'Home',
components: {
'counter' :require('@/components/Counter.vue').default

What would be the default way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 way to import component the first local if this components will be used in only one or 2 page you can import it like this

```
<script> 
import ButtonCounter from './ButtonCounter.vue' 
export default { components: { ButtonCounter } } 
</script>
```

If this components will be used by too much page you can import it globaly like this  in the main.js

```
import MyComponent from './App.vue' 
app.component('ButtonCounter', ButtonCounter)
```